# a question about the divergence of the sum of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

consider a sequence $s_n\in\Bbb{Z}$ and let that the following summation diverges
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{s_n}{n}$$
my question is if based on the fact stated above, can we prove that
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} s_n$$
also diverges?

Comment: Since $s_n \in \mathbb Z$ convergence of the second series implies $s_n  \to 0$ which implies $s_n=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large. So $\sum \frac {s_n} n$ is convergent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you rewrite this as a answer?